# Unable to start application on websphere 8.5, but running on version 7

Tags: java, linux, websphere, cluster-computing

I am having a peculiar problem, I have an ear application containing ejb jars running on websphere 7 standalone. I downloaded version 8.5 trial, created a vertical cluster and installed the application on it. But the application is just not starting on version 8.5. Everytime i try to start it, the log throws an error. Can someone please help me with this ? Please see the SysOut log and FFDC log below.

SystemOut.log

```
[8/29/13 11:29:26:531 IST] 0000009c ApplicationMg A   WSVR0200I: Starting application: <MY_APP>
[8/29/13 11:29:26:532 IST] 0000009c ApplicationMg A   WSVR0204I: Application: <MY_APP>  Application build level: Unknown
[8/29/13 11:29:26:679 IST] 0000009c EJBContainerI E   WSVR0039E: Unable to start EJB jar, <Some ejb jar.jar>: <null>
[8/29/13 11:29:26:684 IST] 0000009c DeployedAppli W   WSVR0206E: Module, <Some ejb jar.jar>, of application, <MY_APP.ear>/deployments/<MY_APP>, failed to start
[8/29/13 11:29:26:699 IST] 0000009c ApplicationMg W   WSVR0101W: An error occurred starting, <MY_APP>
[8/29/13 11:29:26:700 IST] 0000009c ApplicationMg A   WSVR0217I: Stopping application: <MY_APP>
[8/29/13 11:29:26:902 IST] 0000009c ApplicationMg A   WSVR0220I: Application stopped: <MY_APP>
[8/29/13 11:29:27:050 IST] 0000009c CompositionUn E   WSVR0194E: Composition unit WebSphere:cuname=<MY_APP> in BLA WebSphere:blaname=<MY_APP> failed to start.
[8/29/13 11:29:27:089 IST] 0000009c FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on /opt/VCluster/AppNode01/logs/ffdc/server1_4e1dcaf8_13.08.29_11.29.27.0511886725442561483819.txt com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl 679
[8/29/13 11:29:27:173 IST] 0000009c FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on /opt/VCluster/AppNode01/logs/ffdc/server1_4e1dcaf8_13.08.29_11.29.27.0907334828940071905704.txt com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke 679
```

FFDC 1

```
[8/29/13 11:29:27:052 IST]     FFDC Exception:com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning   SourceId:com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl ProbeId:679 Reporter:com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl@d5ac60a1
com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: java.lang.ArrayStoreException
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.createMetaDataCommon(EJBContainerImpl.java:3177)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.createMetaData(EJBContainerImpl.java:3255)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.MetaDataMgrImpl.createMetaDataFromFactories(MetaDataMgrImpl.java:228)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.MetaDataMgrImpl.createMetaData(MetaDataMgrImpl.java:411)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:631)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:774)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1374)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2179)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:445)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:388)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:116)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:663)
at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5474)
at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5600)
at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:677)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:621)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1266)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:49)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor52.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:256)
at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1148)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:252)
at com.ibm.oti.security.CheckedAccessControlContext.securityCheck(CheckedAccessControlContext.java:30)
at sun.misc.JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.doIntersectionPrivilege(JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.java:41)
at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1142)
at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:995)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:848)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:774)
at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1335)
at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1228)
at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181)
at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.CallRouter.route(CallRouter.java:247)
at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink.doWork(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:360)
at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink$IPCConnectorReadCallback.complete(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:602)
at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1784)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:665)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:472)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:298)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation(AnnotationParser.java:234)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:81)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:64)
at com.ibm.oti.reflect.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:63)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredAnnotations(Class.java:1871)
at java.lang.Class.getAnnotations(Class.java:1828)
at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:1808)
at com.ibm.ws.metadata.ComponentDataObject.setInterfacesFromImplements(ComponentDataObject.java:906)
at com.ibm.ws.metadata.ComponentDataObject.finishCDO(ComponentDataObject.java:458)
at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.runtime.SharedEJBRuntimeImpl.createModuleMetaData(SharedEJBRuntimeImpl.java:248)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.createMetaDataCommon(EJBContainerImpl.java:3164)
```

FFDC 2

```
[8/29/13 11:29:27:090 IST]     FFDC Exception:javax.management.MBeanException SourceId:com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke ProbeId:679 Reporter:com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1@8f77d9a9
javax.management.MBeanException: Exception thrown in RequiredModelMBean while trying to invoke operation startApplication
at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1191)
at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:995)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:848)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:774)
at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1335)
at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1228)
at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181)
at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.CallRouter.route(CallRouter.java:247)
at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink.doWork(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:360)
at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink$IPCConnectorReadCallback.complete(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:602)
at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1784)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: java.lang.ArrayStoreException
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.createMetaDataCommon(EJBContainerImpl.java:3177)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.createMetaData(EJBContainerImpl.java:3255)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.MetaDataMgrImpl.createMetaDataFromFactories(MetaDataMgrImpl.java:228)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.MetaDataMgrImpl.createMetaData(MetaDataMgrImpl.java:411)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:631)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:774)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1374)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2179)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:445)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:388)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:116)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:663)
at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5474)
at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5600)
at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:677)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:621)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1266)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:49)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor52.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:256)
at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1148)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:252)
at com.ibm.oti.security.CheckedAccessControlContext.securityCheck(CheckedAccessControlContext.java:30)
at sun.misc.JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.doIntersectionPrivilege(JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.java:41)
at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1142)
... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:665)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:472)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:298)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation(AnnotationParser.java:234)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:81)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:64)
at com.ibm.oti.reflect.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:63)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredAnnotations(Class.java:1871)
at java.lang.Class.getAnnotations(Class.java:1828)
at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:1808)
at com.ibm.ws.metadata.ComponentDataObject.setInterfacesFromImplements(ComponentDataObject.java:906)
at com.ibm.ws.metadata.ComponentDataObject.finishCDO(ComponentDataObject.java:458)
at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.runtime.SharedEJBRuntimeImpl.createModuleMetaData(SharedEJBRuntimeImpl.java:248)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.createMetaDataCommon(EJBContainerImpl.java:3164)
```

Comment: This looks like a JVM error.  I recommend updating to the latest fixpack and trying again.  If the problem persists, I recommend opening a PMR with IBM.

Comment: Are there some SystemErr entries relative to this ?